# TCP-Server over SSL using SocketServer.TCPServer

Tags: python, ssl, tcp, socketserver

i want to add ssl-support to an existing TCP-server which is based on the SocketServer.TCPServer class.
So i overrode the default constructor of the TCPServer class and added the ssl.wrap_socket(...)-call:

```
class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True):
        # See SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__
        # (added ssl-support):
        SocketServer.BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address,
                                                        RequestHandlerClass)
        self.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(
                    socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type),
                    server_side=True,
                    certfile='cert.pem'
                    )

        if bind_and_activate:
            self.server_bind()
            self.server_activate()
```

When starting the server, no error occurrs.
So i modified my simple test-client to support ssl, too:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s)
sock.connect(('192.168.1.1', 54321))
```

Again no error occurrs, but the connect-call is blocking. When closing the client using Ctrl+C it shows the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exampleClient.py", line 10, in <module>
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 293, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So the do_handshake is blocking when connecting. Does anyone knows how to fix the problem? I simply want to use an encrypted TCP-connection :)

Comment: Biggie, please cut your solution out of the question and repost as an answer to your own question.  Then you can accept it, and receive upvotes for the solution.

Comment: Maybe you want to try with standard python ssl module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582766/adding-ssl-support-to-socketserver/17501900#17501900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution. Now i use something similar to 
[this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442473-simple-http-server-supporting-ssl-secure-communica/) using the OpenSSL-package:

Inside the MyTCPServer-Constructor:

```
SocketServer.BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass)
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
cert = 'cert.pem'
ctx.use_privatekey_file(cert)
ctx.use_certificate_file(cert)
self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family,
                                                        self.socket_type))
if bind_and_activate:
    self.server_bind()
    self.server_activate()
```

And in the setup-method of the StreamRequestHandler:

```
self.connection = self.request
self.rfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "rb", self.rbufsize)
self.wfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "wb", self.wbufsize)
```

This seems to work fine :-)

Comment: Hi, do you have a complete working python code for this server. I am struggling a bit to where to put the setup code. Thanks.

Comment: I hacked together a working example based on my old code: [Server](http://pastebin.com/1PDX3HRY), [Client](http://pastebin.com/VaWuMpf7). It's a simple echo-server (supporting SSL) using a handler-thread for each client. It already includes some helper-methods for reading/writing :) Note: For the server you need to specify the certificate-file!

Answer (score 9):

The handshake is blocking because you are wrapping the socket after *binding*; the socket is listening for new connections, there is no *client* yet to accept your connections.

Wrap the socket when accepting a connection instead:

```
class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def get_request(self):
        (socket, addr) = SocketServer.TCPServer.get_request(self)
        return (ssl.wrap_socket(socket, server_side=True, certfile="cert.pem"),
                addr)
```

Now the handshake succeeds because there is a client on the other side to shake hands *with*.

There is no additional work necessary for the stream handler; the python `ssl` library gives you objects with the same interface as `socket.socket()`.

You can also wrap the socket early, but do postpone the handshake until you accept a connection:

```
class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def server_bind(self):
        SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
        self.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(
            self.socket, server_side=True, certfile="cert.pem",
            do_handshake_on_connect=False)

    def get_request(self):
        (socket, addr) = SocketServer.TCPServer.get_request(self)
        socket.do_handshake()
        return (socket, addr)
```

Comment: This is THE response.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer! For Python 3, switch from `SocketServer` to `socketserver`, notice the lower-case letters.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to set the `do_handshake_on_connect` argument in your call to ssl.wrap_socket:

> The parameter do_handshake_on_connect
>   specifies whether to do the SSL
>   handshake automatically after doing a
>   socket.connect(), or whether the
>   application program will call it
>   explicitly, by invoking the
>   SSLSocket.do_handshake() method.
>   Calling SSLSocket.do_handshake()
>   explicitly gives the program control
>   over the blocking behavior of the
>   socket I/O involved in the handshake.

Source: http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html

Comment: Yes, but `do_handshake_on_connect` defaults to `True`. I think that's ok, because the handshake is required to exchange e.g. the encryption keys. When setting this to `False` i think i need to call `do_handshake` manually, which blocks, too :-) But i have no idea why the call blocks and does not return. When using `do_handshake_on_connect=False` without calling `do_handshake` manually and then call the `send`-method of the socket-object (on the client side), the `send` method will block.