# Adding SSL Support to SocketServer

Tags: python, ssl, socketserver

I have a Server based on `ThreadingTCPServer`. Now Ii want to add SSL Support to that Server.
Without SSL it works fine but with SSLv3 I cant connect a Client to the Server, it always throws an exception: `Error 111 Connection Refused`. The error mens there's no SSL Server on that port.

I added the SSL Support based on an example I found here at Stackoverflow.
Here's my code:

Server:

```
class BeastServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True):
        SocketServer.BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address,
                                                        RequestHandlerClass)
        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)
        cert = 'server.pem'
        key = 'key.pem'
        ctx.use_privatekey_file(key)
        ctx.use_certificate_file(cert)
        self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family,
                                                        self.socket_type))
        if bind_and_activate:
        #self.server_bind()
        #self.server_a
```

Client:

```
class Client(object) :

    def verbinden (self, ip_) :

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3, ca_certs='server.pem')
        ssl_sock.connect((ip_, 10012))

        return ssl_sock
```

The key and certificate file is created using open SSL.
I hope somebody can tell me what the problem is.

thanks for your help

best regards patrick

Answer (score 12):

Only use the standard library

Server side :

```
from SocketServer import TCPServer, ThreadingMixIn, StreamRequestHandler
import ssl

class MySSL_TCPServer(TCPServer):
    def __init__(self,
                 server_address,
                 RequestHandlerClass,
                 certfile,
                 keyfile,
                 ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                 bind_and_activate=True):
        TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)
        self.certfile = certfile
        self.keyfile = keyfile
        self.ssl_version = ssl_version

    def get_request(self):
        newsocket, fromaddr = self.socket.accept()
        connstream = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                 server_side=True,
                                 certfile = self.certfile,
                                 keyfile = self.keyfile,
                                 ssl_version = self.ssl_version)
        return connstream, fromaddr

class MySSL_ThreadingTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, MySSL_TCPServer): pass

class testHandler(StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = self.connection.recv(4096)
        self.wfile.write(data)
#test code
MySSL_ThreadingTCPServer(('127.0.0.1',5151),testHandler,"cert.pem","key.pem").serve_forever()
```

Client side :

```
import os
import socket, ssl

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
                           ca_certs="cert.pem",
                           cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                           ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
ssl_sock.connect(('127.0.0.1',5151))
ssl_sock.send('hello ~MySSL !')
print ssl_sock.recv(4096)
ssl_sock.close()
```

works well

Answer (score 4):

In fact ssl from the standard library works ok, maybe the problem with the initial code was that you were not asking the base class not to bind and activate. See below working example based on TCPServer. Certificate and Key files are expected to be in the same directory.

```
import os
import SocketServer

class SSLTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True):
        """Constructor. May be extended, do not override."""
        SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, False)

        dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        key_file = os.path.join(dir, 'server.key')
        cert_file = os.path.join(dir, 'server.crt')

        import ssl
        self.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(self.socket, keyfile=key_file, certfile=cert_file, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)

        if bind_and_activate:
            self.server_bind()
            self.server_activate()
```

Answer (score 1):

- install openssl

```bash
sudo aptitude install python-openssl
```

- Then use following Python code

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import socket, SocketServer

class SSlSocketServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):

    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True):
        SocketServer.BaseServer.__init__(self, server_address,
            RequestHandlerClass)
        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv3_METHOD)
        cert = 'cert.pem'
        key = 'private_key.pem'
        ctx.use_privatekey_file(key)
        ctx.use_certificate_file(cert)
        self.socket = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(self.address_family,
            self.socket_type))
        if bind_and_activate:
            self.server_bind()
            self.server_activate()
    def shutdown_request(self,request):
        request.shutdown()

class Decoder(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):
        self.connection = self.request
        self.rfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "rb", self.rbufsize)
        self.wfile = socket._fileobject(self.request, "wb", self.wbufsize)

    def handle(self):
        try:
            socket1 = self.connection
            str1 = socket1.recv(4096)
            print str1
        except Exception, e:
            print 'socket error',e
def main():
    server = SSlSocketServer(('127.0.0.1', 9999), Decoder)
    server.serve_forever()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

- now test server

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 9999))
sslSocket = socket.ssl(s)
print repr(sslSocket.server())
print repr(sslSocket.issuer())
sslSocket.write('Hello secure socket\n')
s.close()
```