# Adding SSL support to socketserver Python3

Tags: ssl, tcp, python-3.x, openssl, socketserver

I want to add SSL support to Server based on  python3 (version 3.3) socketserver. I've found answer to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582766/adding-ssl-support-to-socketserver), but this code doesn't work in Python 3. Method socket._fileobject is not longer available. Is there any way to get this example running in Python3?