# Python ssl Handshake & Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

Currently implementing code similar to what was presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19803457/4822348) and I was curious as to what is happening under the hood.  Does the SSL handshake occur when the socket is wrapped?  Furthermore, is there a way to access the symmetric key that is being utilized for the data being transmitted over the SSL connection (after the connection is negotiated, that is)?

Comment: What do you mean by "Does the SSL handshake occur when the socket is wrapped?" exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure when the handshake happens.  I was assuming it happened somewhere in the `ssl.wrap_socket` function, but there is one on the client side and on the server side, so I'm just trying to get a feel when that data is being exchanged.

Comment: For details of the SSL handshake (i.e. what happens inside `wrap_socket`) see [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work) at security.se.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I know the technical aspects of _what_ is happening, what I'm not sure of is _when_ it's happening or how to access the details of it - that is the subject of this question.

Comment: @JGrindal: what do you mean with "when". All of it is happening inside the `wrap_socket` on client and server if this is what you mean.